# How to use a python library in node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, swig, npmjs

I'm interested in building an NPM module in order to use the functionality of a well known python library. I've considered building a "Node.js wrapper" that allows me to write in JavaScript. Could someone please explain this process in more detail? Or should I just learn some python? From my research, here's a high level overview:

1. Clone repo of python code and add it to my project's directory (lib folder)
2. List, line by line, all python functions and variables to be "wrapped"
3. Download or install any dependencies or build tools